# inserting non-printables in vi

Tags: vimrc

After a near-crash, the assistance has installed LINUX 20.4 instead of 16.04. When in vi, I try to insert a `^C` using `^V^C` I insert `<ESC>[27;5;99~`

Can someone tell me which initialization file controls this behavior and what I must insert in it?

A long time ago, `^C` could be inserted by `ALT 003`. Is this procedure (or a similar one) lost forever?

First of all, thanks to both.

xterm -v says

```
 "Xterm(353)"
```

vi --version says

```
 "VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Apr 15 2020 06:40:31)"
```

Plus, two pages of info that I will report below

$TERM is xterm

The two pages of extra info from vi --version are

```
Included patches: 1-2269
Modified by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Compiled by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_any_white
+arabic            +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tcl
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       +termguicolors
+autochdir         +float             +multi_byte        +terminal
-autoservername    +folding           +multi_lang        +terminfo
-balloon_eval      -footer            -mzscheme          +termresponse
+balloon_eval_term +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +textobjects
-browse            +gettext           +num64             +textprop
++builtin_terms    -hangul_input      +packages          +timers
+byte_offset       +iconv             +path_extra        +title
+channel           +insert_expand     -perl              -toolbar
+cindent           +job               +persistent_undo   +user_commands
-clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        +vartabs
-clipboard         +keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            +profile           +virtualedit
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           -python            +visual
+cmdline_info      +libcall           +python3           +visualextra
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +viminfo
+conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +vreplace
+cryptv            +listcmds          +rightleft         +wildignore
+cscope            +localmap          -ruby              +wildmenu
+cursorbind        -lua               +scrollbind        +windows
+cursorshape       +menu              +signs             +writebackup
+dialog_con        +mksession         +smartindent       -X11
+diff              +modify_fname      +sound             -xfontset
+digraphs          +mouse             +spell             -xim
-dnd               -mouseshape        +startuptime       -xpm
-ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +statusline        -xsmp
+emacs_tags        +mouse_gpm         -sun_workshop      -xterm_clipboard
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
+ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +tag_binary        
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         -tag_old_static    
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -Wdate-time  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/vim-iU6mZD/vim-8.1.2269=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_REENTRANT -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: gcc   -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -lcanberra -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl     -L/usr/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.8 -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -lm
```

Comment: This is modifyOtherKeys feature, from xterm.  There was a bug in Vim which was fixed regarding this function, so what version is that? Also see `:h modifyOtherKeys` on how to disable this.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Can you share some more details about your terminal, `TERM` environment variable, and what version of vi you are using? You can include them in your post via an [edit].

Comment: Thanks Christian, your fix works. The problem was a destructive interaction of configuration files and env variables.
For what regards :compatible, this brings the vim too back in time, with the loss of the multi-level undo, that is a necessary tool. thanks to all.

Comment: @pietrospizzo if you want to add an answer, please add exact details about how to solve the problem. Referring to comments and help is of course acceptable, but *your fix works. The problem was a destructive interaction of configuration files and env variables.* is a bit too vague

Answer (score 1):

The "equivalent" to dos's alt-numpad in vim is `^VuHHHH` where you can enter four hex digits, or `^VUHHHHHHHH` for 8 digits. The hex number is the unicode code point, so if `^V^C` does not work, you can enter it using `^Vu0003`

Comment: that is not hunder percent correct. You can insert literal keys using CTRL-V in insert mode, see `:h i_CTRL-V` and `:h i_CTRL-SHIFT-V` (for modifyOtherKeys that are active here and is therefore more appropriate in this case)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix to bring the vi back in time to what I was used to is to give the flags `-i NONE -u NONE`. You should also know about `:set compatible`.

For myself, this is preferable; for someone newer to vi/vim, I would recommend learning the new features.

Comment: What's wrong with `:h modifyOtherKeys` and disabling it if you do not like that?